# Why do I have so many changes in my merge request

Tags: git

I have branches: `feature` and `dev`. `Feature` branch was created from `dev`. I want to create merge request from `feature` branch to `dev`. First of all I merge `dev` branch into `feature` branch (because dev branch was updated), I resolved conflicts and successfully merge. But when I create MR in GitLab I see that there are too many changes (that I got from dev). These changes are equal in dev and feature branches, so I don't want to include their in my MR.

Comment: I fear your question does not contain enough detail for us to be able to guess what exactly is wrong. From your description it sounds as if the MR diff view should, having successfully merged `dev` into `feature`, only contain new changes...

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: if a diff view contains many *visually* identical lines as changed, it often is caused by

- newlines changed from `\n` to `\r\n` or vice versa)
- indentation changes (tabs to spaces or vice versa, number of spaces/tabs changes due to automated code formatting).

Ohter than that, please elaborate what exactly is shown as a change which you do not expect to see?